# Prometheus - Compare two labels and keep only one

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I can obtain a label value os_name from two different metrics called here metric1 and metric2. One metric (metric2) have always a result. The other metric (metric1) is sometime empty but when it is not, it's always the good value.

```
Example 1 : 
metric1{os_name=""}
metric2{os_name="windows2008"}

Example 2 : 
metric1{os_name="windows2012"}
metric2{os_name="windows2008"}

Example 3 : 
metric1{os_name="windows2012"}
metric2{os_name="windows2012"}

Exemple 4 : 
metric1{os_name="windows2012"}
metric2{os_name="centos7"}
```

I would like compare both result and keep the first one if it is not empty.

In example1, result should be os_name="windows2008".

In example2, result should be os_name="windows2012".

In example3, result should be os_name="windows2012".

In example4, result should be os_name="windows2012".

In Python i can do it with an operator or :

```
>>> metric1 = ""

>>> metric2 = "windows2012"

>>> metric3 = "windows2008"

>>> metric4 = "centos7"

>>> metric1 or metric2
'windows2012'

>>> metric2 or metric3
'windows2012'

>>> metric3 or metric4
'windows2008'

>>> metric4 or metric3
'centos7'
```

I tried to do an or with prometheus, but it keeps os_name only when metric1 and metric2 have the same value.
Do you know if it's feasible ?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Alban